# How to represent Attributes with Anonymous Alphabets in view blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8:

```
public function index()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

        $departments = HrDepartment::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
    return view('hr.departments.index')->with('departments', $departments);
}
```

view

```
 @foreach($departments as $key => $department)
  <tr>
    <td>
       {{$key+1}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{$department->dept_name ?? '' }}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{isset($department->dept_code) ? $department->dept_code : 'N/A'}}
    </td>
                                           
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I don't want the user to see the real department name ( {{$department->dept_name ?? '' }}), but to make it anonymous.

That is, it can randomize   {{$department->dept_name ?? '' }} and represent each with alphabets. The first one can be A, second B, C, .... Z

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: It's not exactly what you asked for, but you might find `str_rot13` to be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple function using the ID of the department

```php
function toAlphabet($integer){
    $alphabet =   array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    $alpha_flip = array_flip($alphabet);
    if($integer <= 25){
      return $alphabet[$integer];
    }
    elseif($integer > 25){
      $dividend = ($integer + 1);
      $alpha = '';
      $modulo;
      while ($dividend > 0){
        $modulo = ($dividend - 1) % 26;
        $alpha = $alphabet[$modulo] . $alpha;
        $dividend = floor((($dividend - $modulo) / 26));
      } 
      return $alpha;
    }
}
```

you can then do

```php
toAlphabet($department->id);
//26 will give "AA"
//25 will give "Z"
//19682 will give "ACCA"
```